# Unable to upload file with .net core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am struggling to get a basic file upload example to work using .NET Core 2.1.  My technique is based on this [.NET Core file upload article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/#comments) using the simple "small files" example found at the top of that article.

When I invoke the file upload I am getting no files posted to the Upload method...

[image]

Can someone see what is missing here?  Seems so simple to do, but yet, doesn't work.

Here is the minimal code needed to reproduce my current state.

I did "File/New Project/ASP.NET Core Web Application" and used this project template...

[image]

I removed the boilerplate UI and created my own version with a simplified project structure...

[image]

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="file" />

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
                let formData = new FormData();

                for (let x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++) {
                    let file = this.files[x];
                    formData.append(file.name, file);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: './Home/Upload',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (message) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FileUploadIssue.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Upload (List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs (unchanged from project template)**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace FileUploadIssue
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs (unchanged from project template)**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace FileUploadIssue
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json (unchanged from project template)**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for following my tutorial :)

The issue is with your jQuery, specifically this piece of code here :

```
for (let x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++) {
    let file = this.files[x];
    formData.append(file.name, file);
}
```

The first parameter of the append method is actually for "form input" name, not the filename (That will be appended to the request automatically when you append the file on).

If you change your code to read :

```
for (let x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++) {
    let file = this.files[x];
    formData.append('files', file);
}
```

You are all good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable upload multiple files, change `<input type="file" />` to below:

```
<input type="file"  multiple />
```